# Can't get value from getSheetValues()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a bit of problem i can't solve, i'm just getting "undefined" with everything i try. What I do or I want to is compare some numbers from two sheets,  if those sheet values match it should be: match! 131212 = 131212 and what i get is: match! undefined = undefined. I hope you could help me guys!

```js
function najdiVprasanje()
{
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("field_data_field_vprasanje");
  var sheet_novo = ss.getSheetByName("novo");
  var topRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var nid = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 4, topRow, 1);
  var novo_nid = sheet_novo.getSheetValues(2, 1, topRow, 1);

  for(var i=0;i<=topRow;i++)
  {  
    for(var x=0;x<=topRow;x++)
        {
          if(novo_nid[i] == nid[x])
          { 
           Logger.log("match found!" + novo_nid[i] + " == " + nid[x]);
          }
        
        }
  }
```

Comment: the code you provided, I think, is not enough to help you with the solution. You need to post more information, what library you are using, etc. Right now - it's totally out of the context. Please, consider adding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) code snippet to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'ss' represents the spreadsheet(workbook) ? It isn't defined anywhere. If your script is bound to a spreadsheet, your first line should probably look like

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

Comment: `;` is missing, I think.